# Filtering parent object by related object, 2 levels deep

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am looking for a way to filter my set of base objects by checking if a 'grandchild' object is a member of a list of the same type of objects.

For example, I have the following classes:

```
public class Customer
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Order> orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public Datetime OrderDate { get; set; }
     public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of `Products`, maybe something special about them like if they have a discount applied:

```
List<Product> DiscountItems = new List<Product>();
{
     new Product { Id = 0, DepartmentID = 2, Name = "Widget1", Description = "Big widget" },  
     new Product { Id = 1, DepartmentID = 2, Name = "Widget2", Description = "Medium widget" },  
     new Product { Id = 2, DepartmentID = 4, Name = "Widget3", Description = "Small widget" }  
};
```

I would like, using LINQ (or another elegant solution) to create a Collection/List of Customers (along with related Orders and related Products) who have placed orders featuring Products that appear in this list of `DiscountItems`.

I have tried many variations on my statement, with no success at all. Here is an example of what I would like to do (not working, pseudo-ish code):

```
_Customers = await _context.Customers.Select(c => c.orders.Select(o => o.Products
                 .Where(p => DiscountItems.Contains(p)))).ToListAsync();
```

Your help and guidance are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you may want to look at `GroupBy`... group by customer, then by order, then filter (`Where<T>()`) based on whether or not the product is the Discount Items list.

Answer (score 3):

As you've not overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode()` in your `Product` class or implemented `IEqualityComparer<Product>` you're just getting the default comparison, which checks if the references are equal. So what you need is something like this:

```
class ItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{

    public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id &&
            x.Name == y.Name &&
            x.DepartmentID == y.DepartmentID &&
            x.Description == y.Description;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^
            obj.Name.GetHashCode() ^
            obj.DepartmentID.GetHashCode() ^
            obj.Description.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can add the new comparer to your `Contains` method just like this and get your desired results:

```
_Customers = await _context.Customers.Select(c => c.orders.Select(o => o.Products
       .Where(p => DiscountItems.Contains(p, new ItemComparer()))))
       .ToListAsync();
```

Also you may want to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select` in this case to flatten your list and just get a `List` of `Product` as a result instead of getting a `List` of `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable` of `Product`:

```
_Customers = await _context.Customers.SelectMany(c => c.orders.SelectMany(o => o.Products
              .Where(p => DiscountItems.Contains(p, new ItemComparer()))))
              .ToListAsync();
```